# How to I copy one google doc into another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am wondering how to copy a google doc, but include the style, links and font, from within google scripts.
I have tried to use the `getBody()`

```
DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().clear()
document2 = DocumentApp.openById("Document_ID").getBody().getText()
DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().appendParagraph(document2)
```

But that only copies that raw text.

EDIT:
Removed documents because the question was solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `getText` will only return the raw text, nothing more. Treat them as objects instead, iterate, then append one by one.

```
function appendContents() {
  var source = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var destination = DocumentApp.openById("DOC ID");

  var numElements = source.getNumChildren();

  for (var i = 0; i < numElements; ++i ) {
    var body = destination.getBody()
    var element = source.getChild(i).copy();
    var type = element.getType();
    if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH ){
      body.appendParagraph(element);
    }
    // Add other element types if you are expecting other elements
    // e.g. LIST_ITEM, TEXT, TABLE
    // Note that different append will be used for each element type.
  }
  destination.saveAndClose();
}
```

If you want to add other element types, see list of available [ElementTypes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element-type)